# OSX and C++ unicode conversion from NFD to NFC

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, normalization, unicode-normalization

I have a problem with NFD Unicode strings I get from the OSX Filesystem.

This is what I get for the "Ä"-Umlaut on OSX "A\xcc\x88" and this is what I expect "\xc3\x84". The same function does it right under windows (simple boost filesystem operation, listing an directory).

After searching a while, I found out that Apple the NFD coding for UTF-8 and the rest of the world NFC. I tried a bit with converting through NSStrings or with boost::locale::normalize, but without success.

Does anybody know a way to do this in C++ (I can use Cocoa through obj-c if necessary)?

I would like the raw unicode string as std::string (with unicode coding) after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution to get the precomposed form.

```
std::string precomposeFilename(const std::string& name)
{
   CFStringRef cfStringRef = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, name.c_str(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
   CFMutableStringRef cfMutable = CFStringCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, cfStringRef);

   CFStringNormalize(cfMutable,kCFStringNormalizationFormC);

   char c_str[255 + 1];
   CFStringGetCString(cfMutable, c_str, sizeof(c_str)-1, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

   CFRelease(cfStringRef);
   CFRelease(cfMutable);

   return std::string(c_str);
}
```

Comment: How do you convert the NSString-based path to the std::string parameter for precomposeFilename()?

Answer (score 2):

NSString has - (NSString *)precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping function, and some other ones, looks like they will help you.

Comment: But can I get back a useful c string after that? I tried several forms, but nothing was close to what I expected

Comment: Calling [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding] on that NSString should give you what you want, did you try it?

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow (I am feeling sick right now) and give feedback. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for our help, I figured out that CFString is what I was looking for.